# Support Libraries.... Which ones?

Tags: android, android-support-library

So I've read through the documentation on the various support libraries. I'm still confused. I want to target API 11+ and include fragments, viewpagers, etc. Can someone please explain which libraries I need to use?

Basically are v4 and v7 necessary or can I use just v13? I really just don't know which libraries I should use if I'm targeting 11 and above.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for v7 support library, [have look here for detials](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7) (and comparison with other support library versions)

Depending on the component picked, it may require adding v4 as dependency to some of them (for eg: appcompat library). Above link is the go to reference.